# handle checked exception in RxJava 2

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have some issue when I try to catch exception.

I have some method like this (legacy method)  :

```
public String myLegacyMethod throws MyException() {
//do something or throw MyException in case of error
}
```

and I need to send a Single of this part and my solution is:

```
public Single<String> reactiveMethod() {
 try {
  String s = myLegacyMethod();
  return Single.just(s);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  //log exception
  return Single.error(e);
 }
}
```

are there a way to handle an exception in reactive way? or maybe transform reactiveMethod in non-blocking code?

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fromCallable` in 2.x if `MyException` extends `Exception`:

```java
public Single<String> reactiveMethod() {
  return Single.fromCallable(() -> myLegacyMethod());
}
```